# How to get array indexes using lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, lambda

I was trying to create a string joining elements of an integer array:

```
string.Join(", ", integerArray.Select(p => p.ToString()).ToArray())
```

This way I get something like this: `1, 2, 3, 4`.

Now I'd like to print, for each element the index of the corresponding position in the array, something like this: `{0} 1, {1} 2, {2} 3, {3} 4`.

Don't care about format. What I'm wondering is how can I get array index for each selected element in my lambda expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` has an overload that takes the index as an input to the lambda:

```
string.Join(", ", integerArray.Select((p, i) => string.Format("[{0}] {1}",i,p)).ToArray());
```

Note that I use `[]` instead of `{}` just to avoid the ugliness of using curly brackets in `string.Format`.  If you *really* want curly brackets you could do:

```
string.Join(", ", integerArray.Select((p, i) => string.Format("{{{0}}} {1}",i,p)).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 2):

The same as Stanley, just with the curly braces

```
int[] integerArray = {1,2,3,4,5};
string result = string.Join(", ", integerArray.Select((p, i) => string.Format("{{{0}}} {1}", i, p.ToString())).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Note that you need three braces instead of two otherwise you'll get `{0}` for each item.

Comment: Right, fixed now, I have already upvoted your answer, reccomending to the OP to accept yours